# .How to clear custom input in react native using ref

Tags: reactjs, react-native

I'm working on an app which the users will enter large number of records continuously. Currently, I'm using `State` to clearing the input when submit is pressed. So by considering performance issues i'd like to clear the input using `ref` property. So i've tried by using these.

```
1- firstref.current.clear();
2- firstref.current.setNativeProps({ text: '' });
3- firstref.current.value = '';
```

But the input field is not clearing the value after submit. I'm using a custom input component. Here is a demo by clearing the input using state. [Demo using state](https://snack.expo.io/@ssoorajs96/demoprjct)

```
 <View style={styles.fixedform}>
    <View style={styles.textinputViewleft}>
        <TextInput 
        style={styles.textinput} 
        ref={firstref}
        label="Digit"
        returnKeyType="next"
        value={digit.value}
        onChangeText={(text) => { setDigit({ value: text, error: '' }); if (text.length === 3) { ref.current.focus(); } }}
        error={!!digit.error}
        errorText={digit.error}
        keyboardType="numeric"
        maxLength={3}
        minLength={3}/>
    </View>
    <View style={styles.textinputView}>
        <TextInput 
        style={styles.textinput} 
        ref={ref}
        label="Count"
        value={count.value}
        onChangeText={(text) => setCount({ value: text, error: '' })}
        error={!!count.error}
        errorText={count.error}
        keyboardType="numeric"
        maxLength={3}/>
    </View>
    <View style={styles.textinputView}>
        <Button loading={loading} disabled={disabled} style={styles.buttonView} mode="contained" onPress={onSubmitPress}>Submit</Button>
    </View>
  </View>
```

Comment: I did answer this question with working example here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/65597149/12608714 , oh wait you are the same guy!

Comment: @b3hr4d I've tried the method that you've suggested me to do for reducing unwanted rendering . But after implementing that also my issue wat not solved fully. So i came back to the old one and splitted my components into parent and child . That solved my issue but now i'm just trying to reduce the number of state calls . Thatswhy i moved to ref method.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

looks like this is a bug in **TextInput** of **react-native-paper package**.

also this line:

```
scrollViewRef.current.scrollToEnd({animated: true})
```

is giving me an error:

Cannot read property 'scrollToEnd' of undefined.

I commented this like to see what is happening with refs.

First of all, you cannot get the value of TextInput with ref (not yet).

I continue changing the code and i noticed that

```
digitRef.current.focus();
```

this line is focusing and also giving TextInput the previous text!

you can see that by adding setTimeout between focus and clear to see what's happening.

workaround is using TextInput of 'react-native' instead of 'react-native-paper'.

here is a working code:

https://snack.expo.io/@arminya/demoprjct

Answer (score 0):

Instead of using "React.useRef" you should use "React.createRef".

```
const firstref = React.createRef(null);
```

Then

```
firstref.current.clear();
```

will work

Comment: Perhaps can you can further explain why `createRef` is more suitable than `useRef` in this context?

Comment: @D10S I've tried this but still the same issue. Not clearing the value from input.

Comment: I checked it on the snack. it works. you can also add `({ value: '' });`. Note that thise 2 lines need to be called before the function's return.

Comment: @D10S Yes , i've tried as you mentioned here but its showing a error like this Unhandled Rejection (TypeError): firstref.current is null . This is how i implemented
https://jsfiddle.net/ksqguz5p/

Comment: Your problem is in the axios.post statement. You can't use "then" as you did. Try switching the code to async-await as the submit function is already declared as async.

Answer (score 0):

What you looking for is to make react rerender after changing ref which is imposible.

If you want to trigger a re-render after the ref changes, you must use useState instead of useRef. Only that way can you ensure that the component will re-render.

As stated in [React document](https://reactjs.org/docs/hooks-reference.html#useref)

> Keep in mind that useRef doesn’t notify you when its content changes. Mutating the .current property doesn’t cause a re-render. If you want to run some code when React attaches or detaches a ref to a DOM node, you may want to use a callback ref instead.